# Bar cursor in Ymacs

Tags: css

Ymacs editor has a block cursor, and, like my emacs setup, I wanted to have the same cursor; a vertical bar instead of block. I came up with this code:

```css
.Ymacs-Theme-dark .Ymacs_Frame-focus .Ymacs-caret {
    background: transparent !important;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: -1px;
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

But this doesn't work when the cursor is the first character in line, because `margin-left: -1px` will make it outside of the page (it's needed because otherwise the border will move the cursor by one pixel).

Is there a way to make a vertical cursor that will work even as first character of the line?

You can test this on [ymacs demo](http://www.ymacs.org/demo/) page and add my css using dev tools. I can create a CodePen demo if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your custom styles as well:

```css
.Ymacs-current-line {
    padding-left:1px;
}
```

It will add one pixel of padding to the left edge of the active line, enough to see the blinking cursor, and will shift the element right by `1px`, leaving the left edge of the line in the same place, rather than giving you a scrollbar or shifting the cursor over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :before pseudo element like this:

```
.Ymacs-caret {
    position: relative;
}
.Ymacs-caret:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    bottom: 0;
}
```